# How to prevent fonts from rescaling

Tags: unity, 14.04, display, fonts, scaling

In Ubuntu 14.04 there's a new feature that I love called "scale for menu and title bars". It is located in the display settings.

I have set the scaling to 0.875. Since setting this, I have had many issues with the fonts being rescaled at log-in to extremely small sizes (it varies). It also occasionally just changes even without logging out.

In order to fix this, I am having to open either the Unity Tweak Tool (fonts setting) or Ubuntu Tweak and readjust to back to the scale of 1.0.

Is there anyway to configure the system so that it stops rescaling my fonts but keep the scaled menu and titlebars?

Comment: I've also tried unity tweak tool, but for me it created more issues than it solved. every login the font-size got smaller and smaller. after uninstalling it the font-size was still small and large in places. but it didn't shrunk any further.

Comment: @ TD_Nijboer - Thanks for the feedback. The thing is, I never touched my font settings. It wasn't until I changed the menu scaling that the fonts started re-sizing randomly. Only then did I change it with Unity Tweak.

Comment: I have encountered this problem too. After lowering "scale for menu and title bars" after some time the font scaling (accessible in Unity Tweak) became very low and the fonts were almost unreadable. Do you know if there is bug ticket open for this problem?

Comment: I have discovered this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1317253  Could you please add "it affects me" and subscribe to the bug to increase its "heat" and bring enough attention?

Comment: thanks pabouk. I've added myself to the bug report. I suppose this question can be closed now as it does appear to be a bug. However, the workaround is to use one of the Tweak tools to re-adjust the fonts when the issue occurs.

Comment: Thank you rimez. I have noticed that there is an earlier report of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1310316 I have marked the newer one (linked above) as a duplicate.

Comment: This solved it `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Interface text-scale-factor 1.25` for me.